# Faux 3D engines/libs for 2D <canvas>

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, 3d, polygon

I need to draw some textured 3D polygons on 2D  (does not need be perspective corrected or anything very fancy). Are there any free/OSS libs/engines which would do some primitive 3D operations on 2D  context?

Namely I cannot use webGL because of

- Microsoft
- Android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/) you can use canvas (2d context) as a renderer.

Answer (score 0):

**Sprite3D.js** should suits your needs: http://minimal.be/lab/Sprite3D/

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I am really looking for <canvas> solution, not CSS solution